# Parent rounded corners overlap with child

Tags: html, css

I am stuck with a problem, I have a `nav` and in it i got two `div` and in those I got one `li` each. I want the `div`s to overlap the `nav` bar but what is making me stuck is that I want the `nav` bar to get rounded corners where the `div` overlaps it means that the `div`s need to stretch out their corners to make a rounded form for the `nav` bar. Is that possible and how could I do that?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-40deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-40deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
}
nav {
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  top: 505;
  margin-top: -0.4em;
  -webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(40deg);
  -o-transform: skew(40deg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div class="overlapping_div">
      <li>Text in div</li>
    </div>
    <div class="overlapping_div">
      <li>Text in div</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...a `ul` can only have `li` as direct children`. Put the `div` inside the `li`. Also an image of the intended result might be more use.

Answer (score 0):

li needs to be the direct child of a ul, in order to do what you want maybe try this solution:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li class="overlapping_div">
          <span>Text in div</span>
      </li>
      <li class="overlapping_div">
          <span>Text in div</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and the CSS looks like this

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.overlapping_div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-40deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-40deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
}
nav {
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 0;
}
span {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  top : 5px;
  display : block;
  -webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(40deg);
  -o-transform: skew(40deg);
}
```